# Literals in string interpolation expression

Tags: swift

Can I write literals in string interpolation expression? How?

`"Number of items: \(items > 0 ? items :`**`"zero"`**`)"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-ID292) seems to suggest that escaping literals in interpolated strings is somehow possible

> The expressions you write inside parentheses within an interpolated string cannot contain an unescaped double quote (") or backslash (), and cannot contain a carriage return or line feed.

However, to the best of my knowledge, there's currently no way.

Possible workarounds are string concatenation:

```
"Number of items: " + (items > 0 ? "\(items)" : "zero")
```

or simply using a variable

```
let nOfItems = items > 0 ? "\(items)" : "zero"
"Number of items: \(nOfItems)"
```

Comment: You need to use `"\(items)"` in your workarounds or they will not work.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to @Gabriele's solution, you can also use a closure, which has the advantage of being *evaluated at the time the string is rendered*:

```
var items = 0

let formatString = { () -> String in
    let expression = { () -> String in
        return items > 0 ? String(items) : "zero"
    }

    return "Number of items: \(expression())"
}

formatString() // returns "Number of items: zero"

items = 12
formatString() // returns "Number of items: 12"
```

Comment: or you could use a `lazy var`, although it doesn't look like a big concern, in this specific case.

Answer (score 0):

**It works now with Swift 2.1 (since Xcode 7 beta 3).**

From the release notes:

> Expressions interpolated in strings may now contain string literals.

Your example is now valid:

```
let result = "Number of items: \(items > 0 ? String(items) : "zero")"
```

In Swift 2.1 for your specific example there's now a type mismatch between Int and String for the returned result of the ternary operator, so I had to make a tiny change - but the relevant part with `"zero"` is now valid.